# REST: which HTTP Status for rejecting method on current state of resource

Tags: rest, validation, http, api-design, http-status-codes

Imagine the following scenario:

The clients wants to change the state of a resource (e.g `Order`) via **PUT**.
The method is allowed for this resource, but the final state change to `orderState=payed` requires some precondition (like **POST**ing a valid payment resource to the order).
So PUT is only allowed when the target resource is in a specific state.

**What would be a suitable response code?**

I think that `405 - Method Not Allowed` doesn't really fit to this scenario as it implies that the client can't use PUT at all on that resource.

I'm currently considering 409, 423, 424 and 428 but I'd like to know if there are some best practices regarding this specific scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) to cover your case:

> The 405 (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.  The origin server MUST generate an Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.

My reading is that "currently supported" implies that the list of supported methods may evolve over time.

[403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) is also fine:

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.... a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.

As with any 4xx class status-code, the message-body should include "a representation containing an explanation of the error situation", which is where you insert the explanation of the problem.